# Apply different colors to different items of a RadioButtonList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have a `RadioButtonList` like:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("A1") %>'>
  <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" class="radiobuttonlist"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" class="radiobuttonlist"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" class="radiobuttonlist"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" class="radiobuttonlist"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="5" Value="5" class="radiobuttonlist"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to apply  red color to the `ListItem` that its `value` is 1, yellow to the `ListItem` that its `value` is 2, green to the `ListItem` that its `value` is 3 and so on.How do I do It?

I am using ASP.Net web forms. Either jQuery or CSS will do.

The problem is that I have more than 10 radio button lists. I have to set color to all of them like I have mentioned in the question above. Each radio button list obviously has a different Id but all of them have 5 options. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ten `RadioButtonList` and want to do same thing for each of those you can classify each of five `ListItem` and define colors in CSS. example for two `RadioButtonList`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("A1") %>'>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" class="radiobuttonlist1"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" class="radiobuttonlist2"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" class="radiobuttonlist3"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" class="radiobuttonlist4"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="5" Value="5" class="radiobuttonlist5"/>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

---

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("A1") %>'>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" class="radiobuttonlist1"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" class="radiobuttonlist2"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" class="radiobuttonlist3"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" class="radiobuttonlist4"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="5" Value="5" class="radiobuttonlist5"/>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and then in CSS:

```
.radiobuttonlist1{
   color:red;
 }
.radiobuttonlist2{
   color:yellow;
 }
.radiobuttonlist3{
   color:green;
 }
.radiobuttonlist4{
   color:magenta;
 }
.radiobuttonlist5{
   color:blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can give different CSS classes to each `ListItem` then define their color.as this:

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" class="radiobuttonlist1"/>
<asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" class="radiobuttonlist2"/>
```

CSS:

```
.radiobuttonlist1{
     color:red;
 }
.radiobuttonlist2{
     color:yellow;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in code behind you can use this:

```
foreach (ListItem i in rbl1.Items)
     if (i.Value == "1")
         i.Attributes["style"] = "color:red;";
     else if (i.Value == "2")
         i.Attributes["style"] = "color:yellow;";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for each function as follows

```
 $("#rbl1 option").each(function()
 {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
 });
```

this will change the background color of whole items.

In your condition you will have to check the values also

```
 $("#rbl1 option").each(function()
 {
     if($(this).val()=="1")
         $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
     if($(this).val()=="2")
         $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
     if($(this).val()=="3")
         $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
 });
```